# Отправка сообщения в ЛС участника discord.py

Tags: discord.py

Хочу сделать так, чтобы при вводе команды и любого текста, этот текст отправлялся бы в ЛС по айди (в коде изменять айди)

Пример:

```
!команда (текст)
```

И отправляет мне в ЛС:

```
(Текст)
```

мой код: (не работает так, как мне нужно)

```
@bot.command()
async def dm(ctx, user : discord.User, *, msg):
    try:
        await user.send(msg)
        await ctx.send(f':white_check_mark: ')
    except:
        await ctx.send(':x:')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.command
async def dm(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, message):
   await member.send(message)
```